# Using De Morgan's Laws Prove $\operatorname{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)\ge1-\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{P}\left(A^c_i\right)$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I have to prove with De Morgan’s laws that

$$\operatorname{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)\ge1-\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{P}\left(A^c_i\right)$$

but I don’t know how.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** $\left(\bigcup A_i\right)^c=\left(\bigcap A_i^c\right)$ and $\left(\bigcap A_i\right)^c=\left(\bigcup A_i^c\right)$

Further you should know $\sum \Pr(A_i)\geq \Pr\!\left(\bigcup A_i\right)$